# What does it mean to "release sth into sth"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this sentence "release your desired outcome to the wisdom of Reiki" in a presentation about Reiki energy. I would appreciate it if you tell me what the meaning of "release" in the sentence is.

Comment: *Release your desired outcome to the wisdom of Reiki* is not something any native Anglophone would normally say, so there's not much point in asking what it might mean. But I'll take a wild guess that it's from some non-native speaker advising his audience that they should trust Reiki to choose (and pursue?) some "desired outcome" on their behalf (they should metaphorically "release" control of their own actions and desires).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica In new-age thought, personification of "energies" is quite common.  There are lots of native anglophones who do write like this.

Comment: @JamesK: I find that hard to believe - but if so, I would seriously advise ***non-native*** speakers not to copy such people! I think maybe you're focusing on the "woolly thinking" aspect of the cited text rather than the actual vocabulary and syntax. To my mind, almost any native speaker who wanted to write such drivel would go with ***surrender*** rather than ***release***, and would probably also reduce ***desired outcome*** to just ***desire / aspiration / ambition*** or similar (perhaps pluralized).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a metaphor.

Literally if you might say "Release the animal to the wild".  The animal is free to go into the wild countryside.

So here, you allow your "desired outcome" to be free to go into the "wisdom of Reiki".

It is fairly common in spiritual or "new age" writing to use this kind of metaphor.  It means no more or less in English than it would in your language.

Comment: Cruel people often call this type of "New Age" writing "mumbo-jumbo".

Comment: And not only cruel people!